# Why hasn't the tag info page updated within the last few days?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

I was looking at the [JavaScript tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers), which lists the top askers and answered within the tag for the last 30 days.

My personal listing is appended to the end, since I'm ostensibly not within the top 20 for either. I have a total score of 95 for 16 answers and a total of score of 19 for 1 question:

[image]
[image]

At the bottom of the page, it says

```
Only non community-wiki questions and answers are included in these totals (updated daily)
```

However, this doesn't seem to be the case.

I recently posted a [self-answered question about a CSS-only carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295085/how-can-i-make-an-image-carousel-with-only-css), which got a lot more votes than I expected it to: 81 on the question and 133 on the answer.

These votes occurred mainly [on May 18, 27, and 28](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2476755/royhowie?tab=reputation) and should alone put me solidly within the top 20 on this list. Well over a day has passed. Why hasn't this list been updated?

<sup>As an aside, I noticed the count on the JavaScript tag [on my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2476755/royhowie?tab=profile) also hasn't updated for several days.</sup>

Comment: I was going to ask this as well.  I suspect the issues lies in your `aside` - whatever is supposed to update the tag scores is not running, as a result the TopUsers page is also behind.  Seems like it is close to 5 days since it updated.

Comment: This has been going on for a long time. I believe they should normally update once a day, but they often don't. See for example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I read most of those posts when I tried googling my above question before asking. Why do they say that the issue has been fixed and that the script *will* run once a day, if it clearly hasn't been?

Comment: The job that ran this queue was bombing out over the weekend - it's now running again, and we're digging a bit at the cause of the timeouts.

Comment: Tag scores were not updated this morning and yesterday morning.

Comment: @NickCraver I think this is broken again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears the queue just ran:

[image]
[image]

My profile was also updated.

[image: picture of my profile tag score]

I still want to know why the queue took so long to run, however.